# Merging dynamic field with type date/string triggered conflict

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm uploading json files on my Elasticsearch server and I have an object "meta" with a field name and a field value. Sometimes value is a string and sometimes is a date so the dynamic mapping doesn't work.
I tried to put an explicit mapping to set the field to string but I always have the same error **"Merging dynamic updates triggered a conflict: mapper [customer.meta.value] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [date]"}}}, :level=>:warn"**

Can I use the parameter "ignore_conflict" or how can I upload multi type field?

Thx

Comment: It seems that `ignore_conflict` would only mask the issue. It might still hurt you in the future when you try to do searches. If you're okay with it being a string all the time, I would pursue getting that to work. What does your mapping look like?

Comment: Your explicit mapping won't change an existing index.  Did you drop the old one?

Comment: Yes I drop the old one.

Comment: I think the best solution is dynamic mapping but I don't know how if I have two data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two data types for same field in elasticsearch. It is not possible to index it. Dynamic mapping means that the type is identified from the first value that is inserted into the field. If you try to insert some other type in that field, it'll be an error. If you need to store both string and date, your best bet is to set the mapping to use string and explicitly convert your dates to string before passing it to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled date_detection for _ default_ and that's working. 
Now my problem is the following: I want to disable date_detection only for meta.value and customer.meta.value. It's correct for the first but I can't for the second because it's an nested object I think.

I tried this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/rr_sa' -d '
{
   "mappings": {
       "meta": {
           "date_detection": false
         },
        "customer.meta": {
            "date_detection": false
         }
      }
   }
 '
```